# Function in pandas to stack rows into columns by number of rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have heterogeneous dataframe:

```
     a  b  c  d
1    1  2  3  4
2    5  6  7  8 
3    9  10 11 12
4    13 14 15 16
```

And i want to stack the rows like so:

```
     a         b          c          d
1    1,5,8,13  2,6,10,14  3,7,11,15  4,8,12,16
```

Etc...

All the references for grouby etc seem to require some feature of grouping, I just want to put x rows into columns, regardless of their content. Each row has a timestamp, I am looking to group values by sample count, so i want 1 row with all the values of x sample rows as columns.

I should end up with a dataframe that has x*original number of columns and original number of rows/x

I'm sure there must be some simple method I'm missing here without a series of loop etc

Answer (score 2):

If need join all values to strings use:

```
df1 = df.astype(str).agg(','.join).to_frame().T
print (df1)
          a          b          c          d
0  1,5,9,13  2,6,10,14  3,7,11,15  4,8,12,16
```

Or if need create lists use:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[list(df[x]) for x in df]], columns=df.columns)
print (df2)
               a               b               c               d
0  [1, 5, 9, 13]  [2, 6, 10, 14]  [3, 7, 11, 15]  [4, 8, 12, 16]
```

If need scalars with `MultiIndex` (generated fro index nad columns labels) use:

```
df3 = df.unstack().to_frame().T
print (df3)
   a            b             c             d           
   1  2  3   4  1  2   3   4  1  2   3   4  1  2   3   4
0  1  5  9  13  2  6  10  14  3  7  11  15  4  8  12  16
```

Comment: Genius approach to the problem !

Comment: i tried the second method here and it collapsed the entire set into random rows? seems to be no structure at all

Comment: @squashler - Problem in tested data sample? Maybe pandas version problem, tested in pandas 1.2.3.

Comment: I think I'm being unclear about the simplicity of my required output - i just want to append row y with rows x:z so row x is going to get longer

Comment: @squashler - I think not possible in pandas - if you need all data from `df.x` in one cell in DataFrame, e.g. for `x` one cell `x`.